# How to install RSAT on remote Windows 7 workstations using Powershell in 2003 AD

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, powershell, windows

How do I install and enable RSAT tools on remote Windows 7 Workstations using Powershell? 
Actually this process I think has 2 parts:

1. Installing the tools
2. Enabling the features;

How can this be done remotely on windows 7 workstations via powershell? The environment consists only of Windows 2003 R2 domain controllers.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with Powershell? Why don't you just do it the normal way? Such tools shouldn't be put on so many machines that a manual install is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a multi-step process.
You have to install the hotfix using WUSA.exe
then you can use DISM to enable the individual features.
PowerShell instructions at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7900.automate-remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-deployment-using-powershell.aspx

Free Hands On Labs: http://ITProGuru.com/hol